# array passing between numpy and cython

Tags: numpy, cython

I would like to pass an numpy array to cython. The Cython C type should be float. Which numpy type do I have to choose. When I choose float or np.float, then its actually a C double.

Answer (score 1):

You want `np.float32`.  This is a 32-bit C `float`.